# Why does ISDATE(YEAR(GETDATE())) return 1?

Tags: sql-server, date

Why does `ISDATE(YEAR(GETDATE()))` or `ISDATE(2020)` or `ISDATE(<any four digit number>)` or `ISDATE(<any expression that returns a four digit number>)` return a 1?

With all these returning a 1, **can we really rely on ISDATE()** to know if an expression is a date expression?

Here's why I'm concerned:
`SELECT ISDATE(4000-2000)` returns a 1 although it's not a date expression.

Comment: What do you mean by "a date expression"? `SELECT CAST('2000' AS DATE)` returns ``2000-01-01`` - so does cast to date OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `ISDATE` (like `ISNUEMRIC`) isn't a great function. `ISDATE` was designed with the older date and time data types (`datetime` and `smalldatetime`) in mind, which means that a `int` can be implicitly converted to Date and Time. This is **not** true for the new Date and Time datatypes (such as `datetime2` and `date`).

For the older data types, an `int` value represents that many days after `1900-01-01`. So `0` is `1900-01-01`, and `2` would be `1900-01-03`. `2020` would therefore be `1905-07-14`.

If you truly want to see if a value is a valid date and time value, for the data type you are using, use `TRY_CONVERT`. For example `TRY_CONVERT(date,2020)` will return `NULL`, as `2020` cannot be converted. On the other hand `TRY_CONVERT(datetime,2020)` will return `1905-07-14` as it *can* be converted; even if the value isn't what you might expect.

*Additional Note: 4 digit strings can also be implicitly converted. a 4 digit string would represent the year of the date only, and therefore `'2000'` would represent `2000-01-01`. This is true for both the older date and time data types, and the new ones. Both `TRY_CONVERT(date,'2020')` and `TRY_CONVERT(datetime,'2020')` will return `2020-01-01`.*

As Martin Smith mentions, the above is note actually more relevant to what is happening here. As per [ISDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the parameter for `ISDATE` is:

> Is a character string or expression that can be converted to a character string. The expression must be less than 4,000 characters. Date and time data types, except datetime and smalldatetime, are not allowed as the argument for ISDATE.

This means that the expression `ISDATE(2020)` and `ISDATE('2020')` are synonyms. This is actually *really* bad, as `2020` **cannot** be converted to a `date` (implicitly or explicitly), but can be to a `datetime` . This further (in my opinion) cements that `ISDATE` should be avoided. Considering that `TRY_CONVERT` is available in all supported versions of SQL Server (including those in extended support) it is by far a much safer option.

Comment: `SELECT CAST('2000' AS DATE) ` does return `2000-01-01` with the newer datatypes

Comment: @MartinSmith `'2020'` is not an `int`, it is a `varchar(4)`. `2020 <> '2020'` Though I was adding a note about `varchar` behaviour already.

Comment: `ISDATE` accepts a string so all the stuff about `int` is irrelevant. It gets implicitly cast to a string anyway. The execution plan for `SELECT ISDATE(4000-2000) FROM (SELECT 1 AS X) C` - shows that it is calling `isdate(N'2000')`

Comment: You should have lead with that, @MartinSmith :)

Comment: Added extra detail, @MartinSmith . Thanks for pointing out that `ISDATE` implicitly converts to a string type (I suspect an `nvarchar` considering that it needs to be 4,000 characters or less). That is actually a major nail in the functions coffin. Especially as both the new and old date and time datatypes treat `2020` and `'2020'` as very different values.

Comment: yeah - it is nvarchar - it gets constant folded to  `N'2000'` in this case

Comment: '2' is '1900-01-03' but 'ISDATE(2)' returns '0', this is a total mess. Anyway,thanks, @Larnu and Martin, will look into TRY_CONVERT. But alternatively, can I use - (ISDATE(expression) = 1) AND (expression NOT BETWEEN 1753 AND 9999) - will it work just fine or do you see any issue in that?

Comment: Use `TRY_CONVERT` @aditya . Remove any ambiguity from your code.

Answer (score 1):

The date range for `DateTime` is 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31. The year is a valid `datepart`. It does not have to be a string if it is the year only. `SELECT ISDATE('1753')` will return 1 whereas SELECT ISDATE('1752') will return 0. See the full definition [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Yes, year is a valid datepart but so do month and day. But SELECT ISDATE(MONTH(GETDATE())) or SELECT ISDATE(DAY(GETDATE())) return 0.

Comment: They have to return an integer value, converted to a string, between `1753` and `9999` as the definition in my answer. See answer from Lamu for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Because any four digit number is a valid year, therefore it is a date, and the ISDATE() function checks an expression and returns 1 if it is a valid date, otherwise 0.
At 4000-2000 it only checks the return value (2000), which is still valid. If you would give it as a string by parameter ("4000-2000"), it would fail.

Comment: That's what my question is, it treats any four digit number as a year and returns 1. (4000-2000) or 2000 isn't a date. How can we rely on ISDATE()? Is there any better function or option available?

Comment: Same thoughts... four digits when trying to save to a Date field isn't a valid date.  If you try to query a date field that had four digits saved to it... that actual value saved is 01/01/YYYY... where YYYY is the four digit year you saved... there is an automatic application of the month and day being applied magically.  The database is doing an implicit conversion of any four digits into a valid date and then saving it.  I would prefer it did not.  And so now I have to come up with a Regular Expression and SQL Server has crap RegEx support.